# Group by Field MongoDB Java Driver 3+

Tags: java, mongodb, driver

I would like to apply a group operation on my entire Document using MongoDB Java Driver 3.0

My query is something like:

```
db.coll.group( { key: {"field": 1}, cond: {}, reduce: function(curr, result){}, initial: {} } )
```

Results are:

```
{
        "field" : "A61038968K16X275KNWCEIHr"
    },
    {
        "field" : "AH1038968716P3210C6NiQpD"
    },
    {
        "field" : "AV1038968F16Q321DCxY7T6w"
    },
    {
        "field" : "A71038968K165321PLiEhbGJ"
    },
    {
        "field" : "AY1038968N16w321a537co1U"
    },
    {
        "field" : "AJ1038968E16S3212MJpeNNV"
    }
```

I'm trying things in Java like : `collection.aggregate(group("field"))` but it doesn't work. Sorry if it's easy but I can't find anything googling.

Thanks!

Comment: I tried something and maybe not good solution but i think i can helpful for you `Iterable<Document>  output = coll.aggregate( (List<? extends Bson>) Arrays
    .asList((DBObject) new BasicDBObject("$group", (DBObject) new BasicDBObject("_id", "$field")
      .append("count", (DBObject) new BasicDBObject("$sum", 1)))));`

Answer (score 0):

So, what I was looking for was a 'distinct' method.

My solution was:

```
collection.distinct(<string field>, <query>, <result class>);
```

For example, in my case, my result class is a String.

```
collection.distinct("field_grouping",gte("field_query", 1000),String.class);
```

After that you can iterate your results and do whatever you want:

```
Iterator<String> iterator = collection.distinct("field_grouping",gte("field_query", 1000),String.class).iterator();
```